# Exporting dll out of a process memory

Tags: dll, memory-dump

Idk if this is asked before sorry

So I tried something with Process Hacker and Windbg but it couldn't help me
The dll is injected using  `CreateRemoteThread`, `LoadLibrary` i tried looking through files but im a newbie so i didn't got so much experience.
What way would you guys prefer to export a dll of process memory?

Comment: Do you mean "export" as in save the content of the loaded DLL (using the original loaded DLL files would be easier) or do you mean "export" like unload/remove the loaded library?

Comment: saving it, is it possible?

Comment: Why? You can use Sysinternals ProcessMonitor to check which libraries are loaded and the simply copy the DLL file from file-system. No need to extract/export anything from a running process.

Comment: I tried it but the dll gets deleted after injection.

Comment: If you know the file name or the directory you can create a program that waits for file-system modifications and automatically opens and locks all created files in a folder, or if possible hook the process the dll is injected into overwrite Load library method (e.g. using Frida) and let it wait a few seconds, then you have plenty of time to copy the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the library is indeed loaded using LoadLibrary, it must exist on disk. You can, for example,  check the list of modules using Process Explorer or similar and look for it on disk, or catch the load event in the debugger - the file should be available at that point even if it’s deleted afterwards.

Comment: the file isn't shown in modules list i will test catching the load event in the debugger

Comment: Putting breakpoint on LoadLibrary is another option

Comment: Just a thought, how do you know the DLL remains resident after being loaded? In theory it'd also be possible for a DLL to get loaded, do whatever it wants to do and then get unloaded. But Igor's suggestions are probably _the_ way to go for starters.